# netbeans: how can i add an included directory for code completion in php

Tags: php, netbeans

i'm using Zend Framework classes and i don't get code completion for them because the library
directory of Zend Framework in not inside my project. is there a way to tell netbeans to recognize the zend framework directory in order for the code completion to work?  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have to add Zend to Global Include Path. You may do it for the single project only, but it is better to set it in general PHP options (Tools-Options-PHP)

Here is the [tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/using_zend_framework_with_netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

it appears that all i need to do is to manually add the directory to the include path of the project under Project -> Properties-> 'PHP Include Path'

'Global PHP Include Path' is already marked there but unfortunately it does not add the global php include path to the code completion, directories need to be added manually.